# Pandas argmax() deprecation message

Tags: python, pandas, deprecation-warning

When using `argmax()` it returns:

> The current behaviour of `Series.argmax` is deprecated, use `idxmax`
>   instead. The behavior of  `argmax` will be corrected to return the
>   positional maximum in the future. For now, use `series.values.argmax`
>   or `np.argmax(np.array(values))` to get the position of the maximum
>   row. 
>     """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

Any ideas what this means? I have used  `np.argmax(np.array(values))` to get the position of the maximum row but it just returns the max value. `idxmax` returns another error.

Comment: What error are you getting from `idxmax`? The docs for `idxmax` state: "This method is the DataFrame version of ndarray.argmax," so seems like you should use that.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'idmax'

Comment: It’s idxmax. There’s an x

Answer (score 2):

Here is example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

In[3]:
    mtx = np.random.randn(10)
    mtx

Out[3]:
    array([-1.47694909, -0.61658367, -1.2609941 ,  0.33956725,  1.69096661,
    0.10680407, -3.53473223,  0.61587513,  2.34405466, -1.49556778])

In[4]:
    ser = pd.Series(mtx)
    ser

Out[4]:
    0   -1.476949
    1   -0.616584
    2   -1.260994
    3    0.339567
    4    1.690967
    5    0.106804
    6   -3.534732
    7    0.615875
    8    2.344055
    9   -1.495568
    dtype: float64

In[5]:
    ser.idxmax()
Out[5]:
    8


In[6]:
    ser[ser.idxmax()]
Out[6]:
    2.344054659817029
```